# Azure run-command returns truncated output

Tags: linux, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli, az

I run a simple command to get the list of all processes:

```
az vm run-command invoke -g myGroup -n MyVm --command-id RunShellScript --scripts "ps"
```

I get the response back, but it seems to be thoroughly truncated (last X characters is returned). I have not found any documentation on how it is supposed to be and is it a bug or some parameter does exist to fix it?

P.S. This is a linux vm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `run-command` execute the scrips within the Azure VM. Please note that lists of [restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-command#restrictions) are present when using Run Command.

> - **Output is limited to the last 4096 bytes**
> - The minimum time to run a script about 20 seconds
> - Scripts run by default as elevated user on Linux
> - One script at a time may run
> - Scripts that prompt for information (interactive mode) are not supported.
> - You cannot cancel a running script
> - The maximum time a script can run is 90 minutes, after which it will time out
> - Outbound connectivity from the VM is required to return the results of the script.

You also could check the output via navigate to your Azure VM and select **Run command** under **Operations**.

[image]

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Yes, thanks, this at least confirms that there is this limitation and there is probably no way to work around it. I was also wondering if you know if there is a way to format output the was as in picture? It comes as a json back in a command

Comment: AFAIK, you could add `--output` in your `AZ` CLI command,   [--output {json,jsonc,table,tsv,yaml,none}] check the Global Parameters, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/run-command?view=azure-cli-latest#required-parameters

Comment: Thanks, it does indeed change the format, though for some reason Table format does not return anything, I guess it's not quite supported